# flask and url_for() and werkzeug.routing.BuildError

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

This is a pretty simple blueprint/controller:

```
maintenance_controller = Blueprint('maintenance', __name__, url_prefix='/maintenance')

@maintenance_controller.route('/csv', methods=['GET','POST'])
def csv():
    return render_template('/maintenance/csv.html')
```

Then, in `csv.html`:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('csv') }}">
...
</form>
```

However, this yields an exception:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError
BuildError: ('/csv', {}, None)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to give a *blueprint-relative* path:

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('.csv') }}">
```

provided the template is in the same blueprint. For templates outside of the blueprint you need to include the blueprint name:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('maintenance.csv') }}">
```

See the [*Building URLs* section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/#building-urls) of the Blueprints documentation.